# Error while Deserializing JSON output

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, linkedin-api

I am getting the following error at `dynamic jsonText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);`

ERROR

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line
>   0, position 0.

CODE

```
string api = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,formatted-name,email-address)";
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
{
    webClient.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Authorization, "Bearer " + token);
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(api );
    dynamic jsonText = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

}
```

Comment: it is because the server is throwing an error and returning HTML, probably a standard 500 error page or a 401. Html cannot be deserialized as JSON. You need to figure out what the error is and correct it.

Comment: The output i get is a XML. and it's being returned by Linkedin. How can I solve this issue.

Comment: First, actually look at your `json` variable and read it to see if it is a error html page. If not then deserialize the xml because that is probably all you can get based on FRL's answer and your response. (See this)[http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJson.htm]

Comment: @Illep, FRL is on to something. you should read the documentation linked to in that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is necessary to specify that you want the result in json, otherwise some web services returns the data in xml

```
webClient.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Accept, "application/json");

//also the encoding if need
webClient.Headers.Add(System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "utf-8");
```

but in linkedin you must use

```
webClient.Headers.Add("x-li-format", "json");
```

More info here

https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: Yes correct. Or simply you can append `?format=json` to the end of your URI.